# git stash unable to refresh, how to pop only some files

Tags: git

I've stashed my changes in order to do a git pull, but now I can't pop the changes out of my stash.  It looks like this:

```
dave@apollo % git stash pop 
sites/all/themes/foobar122/node--pin.tpl.php: needs merge
unable to refresh index

dave@apollo % git stash show  
 .htaccess                                            | 10 +++++-----
 phpinfo.php                                          |  4 +++-
 sites/all/modules/ajax_comments/ajax_comments.module |  6 +++---
 sites/all/themes/foobar122/node--pin.tpl.php         | 14 +++++++-------
 4 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
```

Can someone explain in simple terms how I can revert the file in conflict (accept their copy) while restoring my changes to the files that have no conflict.

Comment: 4 years later and still no answer to this...
I'm sitting with about 1k line changes in a stash that can't get applied because 1 file is blocking the Stash Pop